# How to create a function in A-FRAME to change only the Z position, keeping Y a Z original values of objects?

Tags: javascript, position, aframe

How can I click on a button and transform / put all objects / at the same distance "z" from the camera, keeping their relative positions "x" and "y"

I want to click on a button and display stuff independantly of the Z, display them independantly from the distance to the camera, keeping theirs original and different values  X and Y original positions.

I intend with javascript, to zoom objects to a position of near distance to camera, with visualization of all the objects, allowing the same reading, even of the more distant objects

What is the javascript solution in A-FRAME, could someone exemplify with a working solution?

Thanks in advance

Miguel Nunes

Answer (score 0):

Get desired z pos in world space:

```
var distance = 5;
var absCameraPos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
cameraEl.getObject3D('camera').getWorldPosition(absCameraPos);
```

Place objects at that world Z. Something like:

```
var tempVec3 = new THREE.Vector3().copy(absCameraPos);
someObjectEl.worldToLocal(tempVec3);
someObjectEl.position.z = tempVec3.z;
```

Comment: What is wrong in this code/script, to make it work for several objects?                                                                       function view_all() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#box");
 var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
var xx = el.getAttribute('position').x;
var yy = el.getAttribute('position').y;
    x[i].setAttribute('position',  {x: xx, y: yy, z: -1});
    }
}

Comment: Didn't you want the objects to be at same distance from camera? That doesn't take into account the camera nor rotation of the camera.

Comment: @MiguelNunes your code tries to grab multiple objects with the id `box`. id's are unique, you should make your entities have a `class=box` and grab `querySelectorAll(".box")`.